# Add comment link is accompanied by a message for newbs on deleted posts

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-questions

So this is pretty minor in the grand scheme of things. But, well it's still a bug.

[image: why me this is so unfair this always happens to me how do i type a question]

The "add comment" link is correctly greyed out, but it is accompanied by a "requires 50 reputation" link that — at 83,921 rep — I've never seen before.

Presumably this shows up pre-login? If so, it's now started showing up for *everybody* on deleted questions.